# Update the table only by matching id using text file in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

We have table like below in postgres database

```
id   resourceid   name         uuid
101  103          RHQ Agent    5422a14f-b68d-4a44-8de6-c1779eeec1f3
108  107          Stable env   01bd63cd-23cb-4c2e-8ae3-ec1c6e1971bb
103  115          kb tier      01bd63cd-23cb-4c2e-8ae3-ec1c6e1971cc
102  104          JON Server   95f0d1b3-ff5f-46fa-95ac-09425db933b2
```

which has more than 100 records

```
**We have text file as**

id        name

101      JON Agent

102      unstable env
```

## Expected output:

```
**id   resourceid   name              uuid**

101    103          JON Agent         5422a14f-b68d-4a44-8de6-c1779eeec1f3

108    107          unstable env      01bd63cd-23cb-4c2e-8ae3-ec1c6e1971bb

102    104          Jboss Server      95f0d1b3-ff5f-46fa-95ac-09425db933b2
```

## Requirement:

We need to change the names of resources using GUI(JON monitoring tool) since it has many resources we decided to done it by updating the names directly in database.

By using JON cli we fetched the ID of each resource name so our text file will have **ID and NAMES** that need to be changed as mentioned above.

We need to update the table (column = name)using our text file only for matching id (only 'name' column should be changed not other columns)as i mentioned in expected output.

More than 100 record need to be updated .Please help on this.

Comment: What are you asking? What does your GUI have to do with this?

Answer (score 2):

If all you are trying to do is update a field in an existing table with data from a text file, it is very simply done using SQL (no GUI necessary):

```
-- Create a table to store data from the text file
CREATE TABLE import_data (id INT, name TEXT);

-- Import the data to the new table
COPY import_data FROM '/path/to/my/textfile.txt' CSV HEADER DELIMITER E'\t';

-- Update the existing table with the names from the imported data, using id to match
UPDATE my_table
SET name = import_data.name
FROM import_data
WHERE my_table.id = import_data.id;

-- Drop the import data table
DROP TABLE import_data;
```

In case your text file uses a different delimiter or has quotes, see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html